# PHP-CodeBrowser not following path in checkstyle.xml correctly

Tags: phpunit, cruisecontrol, phpundercontrol, phpcodesniffer, php-codebrowser

I've set up [phpUnderControl](http://www.phpundercontrol.org/) and it's all working very well, except that for a few projects that I have aren't getting any output in the PHP-CodeBrowser tab.

If I run the command manually I get:

```
phpcb --log projects/devvo/build/logs --source projects/devvo/source --output projects/devvo/build/php-code-browser

Generating PHP_CodeBrowser files
PHP-CodeBrowser Error:
File projects/devvo/source/CLV2/webroot/maintenance.php does not exist!

Script took 2.64733099937 seconds to execute
```

Which I can track into the checkstyle.xml output of PHP-CodeSniffer. It contains:

```
 <file name="/opt/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3/projects/devvo/source/modules/project-creator/source/CLV2/webroot/maintenance.php">
  <error line="2" column="1" severity="error" message="You must use &quot;/**&quot; style comments for a file comment" source="PEAR.Commenting.FileCommentSniff"/>
 </file>
```

What I can't work out is why phpcb is dropping half of the path. I'm guessing that it's some form of path replacement (based on my --source path) having issues with the fact that `source` appears in the path twice. Note that the section of the path that is missing is the bit between the source path specified and the last `source`.

Have I found a bug in phpcb? If so, where can I report it? The closest I have found to where phpcb lives is the link on the [phpUnderControl release page](http://manuel-pichler.de/archives/69-phpUnderControl-0.5.0-released.html) which unfortunately links to a broken URL in the phpUnit github.

Comment: cant help you with your problem, but the code browser is from mayflower, see http://blog.thinkphp.de/archives/464-PHP_CodeBrowser-Release-version-0.1.0.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. More people need to link to the site obviously as I couldn't find it in google (maybe I just fail at searching).

Comment: Does anyone have a way to contact the makers? I left a comment on the above blog post, but it seems to still be stuck in moderation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can try to contact them at <http://www.mayflower.de/en/contact>
```